# I am having an issue in using my C++ and python oot blocks with my gnuradio C++ flowgraph

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gnuradio

I am using C++and python oot blocks in my C++ flowgraph but while executing the flowgraph it gives this error

```
Executing: cmake .. && cmake --build . -j3 && cd ../.. && /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator -e /home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/build/Cpprfdf

-- Using GMP.
-- User set python executable /usr/bin/python3
-- Checking for module 'alsa'
--   No package 'alsa' found
-- Checking for module 'jack'
--   No package 'jack' found
-- Checking for module 'portaudio-2.0'
--   No package 'portaudio-2.0' found
-- Could NOT find libiio (missing: libiio_LIBRARY libiio_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Could NOT find libad9361 (missing: libad9361_LIBRARY libad9361_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Checking for module 'Qt5Qwt6'
--   Package 'Qt5Svg', required by 'Qt5Qwt6', not found
-- QWT Version: 6.1.4
-- Checking for module 'uhd'
--   No package 'uhd' found
-- Could NOT find Codec2 (missing: LIBCODEC2_LIBRARIES LIBCODEC2_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
CMake Warning at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/gnuradio/gnuradio-soapyConfig.cmake:12 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindSoapySDR.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "SoapySDR",
  but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "SoapySDR" with any
  of the following names:

    SoapySDRConfig.cmake
    soapysdr-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "SoapySDR" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "SoapySDR_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "SoapySDR" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/gnuradio/GnuradioConfig.cmake:105 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package)


-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/build
[ 25%] Automatic MOC for target Cpprfdf
[ 25%] Built target Cpprfdf_autogen
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target Cpprfdf
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Cpprfdf.dir/Cpprfdf.cpp.o
/home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/Cpprfdf.cpp: In constructor ‘Cpprfdf::Cpprfdf()’:
/home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/Cpprfdf.cpp:46:37: error: redeclaration of ‘std::vector<std::complex<float> > taps’
   46 |             std::vector<gr_complex> taps = {640};
      |                                     ^~~~
/home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/Cpprfdf.cpp:37:37: note: ‘std::vector<std::complex<float> > taps’ previously declared here
   37 |             std::vector<gr_complex> taps = {640};
      |                                     ^~~~
/home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/Cpprfdf.cpp:55:37: error: redeclaration of ‘std::vector<std::complex<float> > taps’
   55 |             std::vector<gr_complex> taps = {640};
      |                                     ^~~~
/home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/Cpprfdf.cpp:37:37: note: ‘std::vector<std::complex<float> > taps’ previously declared here
   37 |             std::vector<gr_complex> taps = {640};
      |                                     ^~~~
/home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/Cpprfdf.cpp:64:37: error: redeclaration of ‘std::vector<std::complex<float> > taps’
   64 |             std::vector<gr_complex> taps = {640};
      |                                     ^~~~
/home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/Cpprfdf.cpp:37:37: note: ‘std::vector<std::complex<float> > taps’ previously declared here
   37 |             std::vector<gr_complex> taps = {640};
      |                                     ^~~~
/home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/Cpprfdf.cpp:73:37: error: redeclaration of ‘std::vector<std::complex<float> > taps’
   73 |             std::vector<gr_complex> taps = {640};
      |                                     ^~~~
/home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/Cpprfdf.cpp:37:37: note: ‘std::vector<std::complex<float> > taps’ previously declared here
   37 |             std::vector<gr_complex> taps = {640};
      |                                     ^~~~
/home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/Cpprfdf.cpp:218:42: error: ‘class Cpprfdf’ has no member named ‘additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_0’
  218 |     this->tb->hier_block2::connect(this->additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_0, 0, this->kraken_doa_music_0, 4);
      |                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/Cpprfdf.cpp:218:86: error: ‘class Cpprfdf’ has no member named ‘kraken_doa_music_0’
  218 |     this->tb->hier_block2::connect(this->additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_0, 0, this->kraken_doa_music_0, 4);
      |                                                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/Cpprfdf.cpp:219:42: error: ‘class Cpprfdf’ has no member named ‘additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_1’
  219 |     this->tb->hier_block2::connect(this->additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_1, 0, this->kraken_doa_music_0, 3);
      |                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/Cpprfdf.cpp:219:86: error: ‘class Cpprfdf’ has no member named ‘kraken_doa_music_0’
  219 |     this->tb->hier_block2::connect(this->additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_1, 0, this->kraken_doa_music_0, 3);
      |                                                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/Cpprfdf.cpp:220:42: error: ‘class Cpprfdf’ has no member named ‘additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_2’
  220 |     this->tb->hier_block2::connect(this->additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_2, 0, this->kraken_doa_music_0, 1);
      |                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/Cpprfdf.cpp:220:86: error: ‘class Cpprfdf’ has no member named ‘kraken_doa_music_0’
  220 |     this->tb->hier_block2::connect(this->additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_2, 0, this->kraken_doa_music_0, 1);
      |                                                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/Cpprfdf.cpp:221:42: error: ‘class Cpprfdf’ has no member named ‘additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_3’
  221 |     this->tb->hier_block2::connect(this->additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_3, 0, this->kraken_doa_music_0, 2);
      |                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/Cpprfdf.cpp:221:86: error: ‘class Cpprfdf’ has no member named ‘kraken_doa_music_0’
  221 |     this->tb->hier_block2::connect(this->additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_3, 0, this->kraken_doa_music_0, 2);
      |                                                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/Cpprfdf.cpp:222:42: error: ‘class Cpprfdf’ has no member named ‘additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_4’
  222 |     this->tb->hier_block2::connect(this->additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_4, 0, this->kraken_doa_music_0, 0);
      |                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/Cpprfdf.cpp:222:86: error: ‘class Cpprfdf’ has no member named ‘kraken_doa_music_0’
  222 |     this->tb->hier_block2::connect(this->additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_4, 0, this->kraken_doa_music_0, 0);
      |                                                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/Cpprfdf.cpp:223:42: error: ‘class Cpprfdf’ has no member named ‘additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_5’
  223 |     this->tb->hier_block2::connect(this->additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_5, 0, this->blocks_vector_to_stream_0, 0);
      |                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/Cpprfdf.cpp:229:78: error: ‘class Cpprfdf’ has no member named ‘additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_4’
  229 |     this->tb->hier_block2::connect(this->blocks_stream_to_vector_0, 0, this->additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_4, 0);
      |                                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/Cpprfdf.cpp:230:78: error: ‘class Cpprfdf’ has no member named ‘additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_1’
  230 |     this->tb->hier_block2::connect(this->blocks_stream_to_vector_1, 0, this->additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_1, 0);
      |                                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/Cpprfdf.cpp:231:78: error: ‘class Cpprfdf’ has no member named ‘additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_0’
  231 |     this->tb->hier_block2::connect(this->blocks_stream_to_vector_2, 0, this->additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_0, 0);
      |                                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/Cpprfdf.cpp:232:78: error: ‘class Cpprfdf’ has no member named ‘additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_2’
  232 |     this->tb->hier_block2::connect(this->blocks_stream_to_vector_3, 0, this->additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_2, 0);
      |                                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/Cpprfdf.cpp:233:78: error: ‘class Cpprfdf’ has no member named ‘additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_3’
  233 |     this->tb->hier_block2::connect(this->blocks_stream_to_vector_4, 0, this->additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_3, 0);
      |                                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/Cpprfdf.cpp:241:42: error: ‘class Cpprfdf’ has no member named ‘kraken_doa_music_0’
  241 |     this->tb->hier_block2::connect(this->kraken_doa_music_0, 0, this->additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_5, 0);
      |                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/namanchaudharyy/gnuradio flowgraphs/Cpprfdf/Cpprfdf.cpp:241:71: error: ‘class Cpprfdf’ has no member named ‘additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_5’
  241 |     this->tb->hier_block2::connect(this->kraken_doa_music_0, 0, this->additionalblocks_bufferblockcpp_5, 0);
      |                                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Cpprfdf.dir/build.make:90: CMakeFiles/Cpprfdf.dir/Cpprfdf.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:84: CMakeFiles/Cpprfdf.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2

>>> Done (return code 2)
```

I make the changes in .cpp , .hpp , and cmakelists,txt files of the flowgraph to resolve these errors but when I execute the flowgraph in gnuradio it overwrites the changes and again give these errors

I want to know if there is a way to stop this overwrite process of gnuradio or any other way so that the blocks are automatically declared in the flowhraphs hpp file when I execute the flowgraph.